# display the name but insert the id whit entity field type

Tags: symfony

**the form is the entity services**

```
    namespace Main\HomeBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

    class ServicesType extends AbstractType
    {
            /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('techId', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'MainHomeBundle:Technical',
                    'property' => 'id',
                ))
                ->add('status', 'choice', array(
                        'choices'   => array(
                        'pending'   => 'Pending',
                        'finished' => 'Finished',
                    ), 'multiple'  => false), array('required'=>true))
                ->add('payment', 'text', array('required'=>true))
                ->add('endtime', 'datetime', array('required'=>true))
                ->add('send', 'submit')
            ;
        }

        /**
         * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
         */
        public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Main\HomeBundle\Entity\Services'
            ));
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return 'main_homebundle_services';
        }
    }
```

Use this method to display a select users in a update form. The problem is that when the data are sent , send the name and want to send the id while showing the names in the select.

***not use relationships in the database or the entities***

Entity Services **The technical id want to be inserted in techId of Services**

```
class Services
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customer_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $customerId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tech_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $techId;
```

**techId is linking with another entity**

```
class Technical
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     * min = 8,
     * max = 55,
     * minMessage = "{{ limit }}",
     * maxMessage = "{{ limit }}"
     * )
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=55, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }
```

***only informative way because there is no relationship in the database or entities***

Comment: please show your complete FormType and User Entity

Comment: why do you need to send the id?

Comment: Add more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Entity field is the wrong thing to use in this case - the form will try to map an instance of the Technical class onto the Services's integer $techId field, which cannot work.

You need to use a standard choice field and pass the list of (Technical entity) id choices into buildForm() as an option.

In the form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('techId', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $options['techChoices'],
            ))
    ...
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'techChoices' => array(),
    ));
}
```

In the controller:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainHomeBundle:Technical');
$technicals = $repository->findAll();
$techChoices = array();
foreach($technicals as $t) { $techChoices[$t->getId()] = $t->getName(); }

$formOptions = array('techChoices' => $techChoices);
$form = $this->createForm(new ServicesType(), $aServices, $formOptions);
```

Comment: How recommend taking the values ​​and empty in an array in the controller?

Comment: @Eguiarte I don't understand your comment but I have edited my answer to provide code for populating the $techChoices array in the controller. You can find out how to do this in a custom repository class here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes. If you want to do this and can't work it out you need to post a separate question.

Comment: @Eguiarte Note - I don't advocate using shorthand variable names like '$t' but it made the code more readable for this post.

Comment: That was my question , thank you for taking the time to address my problem , you 're a good person.